# what is this "QuartzCore... CA::Transaction::observer_callback.." in my Instruments Leaked Blocks History table?

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks, xcode4, instruments

what is this "QuartzCore... CA::Transaction::observer_callback.." in my Instruments Leaked Blocks History table?

Note that I was creating some hardware memory warnings using the simulator when I was profiling this.

```
QuartzCore  CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver", unsigned long, void")
from main:14 => "int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);"
```

Image Below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is from Core Animation.

Usually when the mainloop completes a full pump and finally paints to the screen with Core Animation, the top level NSAutoreleasePool is flushed at that point.

I'm not to date on the specific details of when it's supposed to happen, but in the UIApplicationMain function, a nested NSAutoreleaesPool is created for the entire main thread scope. It's generally accepted that when the pump is completed it should flush (although it may release later but it's an implementation detail left up to Apple).

What you see there with all those releases from that function is all the actual releases on all the autorelease calls you queued up from before.

Comment: ok thanks Zac - so in summary what I'm seeing is normal than correct?

Comment: yep. completely. Core Animation retains your object to set it different values to test how it will change for an animation transaction. I believe it may create it's own autorelease pool at the top of the transaction and release its own pool at the bottom so it may not be at a full pump here.